# Updating entity classes generated from a database by Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I have generated my entity classes using NetBeans "Entity Classes from Database..." wizard. I now need to add some columns to a few tables in my database. Is there anyway to make NetBeans update the entity classes it generated or do I have to delete the current entities and make NetBeans generated new ones?

Answer (score 3):

Simply rerun the "Entity Classes from Database" wizard. Your Entity Classes will be updated. Anyway, changes you made after the first run of the wizard will be lost!